# Xamarin Hot Restart - Debug iOS App on local device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Is there a way to debug an iOS app developed in Visual Studio with Xamarin Hot Restart for free (without the $99 subscription to the Apple Developer program) on my own Iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, it's not possible to use `Xamarin Hot Restart` when you don't have the Apple Developer account and paid [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) enrollment.

Here are the requirements below when using `Xamarin Hot Restart`:

- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5 or higher
- iTunes (Microsoft Store or
  64-bit versions)
- Apple Developer account and `paid Apple Developer Program` enrollment

You can refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) for more details.